# Probability number is divisible by half the square of a prime?

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, riemann-zeta

Let $p$ be a prime. What is the probability that a number of the form $\left \lceil \frac{p^2}{2} \right \rceil$ divides a random positive integer $n$. I have a solution that involves the Riemann-Zeta Function. However, I think that is overkill as the answer is rational. Does anyone have a more appropriate solution?

Comment: It is difficult to pick an umbounded random positive integer with uniform probability, but in a sense the probability that it will be divisible by a given positive integer $m$ is $\dfrac1m$

Comment: More formally the limit as $k$ approaches infinity of of the probability if $n$ is randomly chosen uniformly from the first $k$ positive integers.